# Joining columns from same table twice causes unknown column issue

Tags: mysql

So interesting thing happening here, i'm using MySql DB and trying to make a join based on the same column from the same table (which i've selected under different aliases). If anyone can tell me the cause of this issue and/or maybe fix my SQL, I would appreciate it.

What i have is three tables:

Tourneyplayers:

```
tp_id | tourneyId | ageId
1     | 1         | 1
2     | 1         | 1
3     | 1         | 2
```

This has all major player data related to my tournament. It links together actual player profile and tournament.

Heats:

```
heatId | heatNumber
1        1
2        3
3        4
```

Heats is basically a group for motos.

Motos:

```
mid | idHeat | result | tpid
1   | 1      | 1      | 1
2   | 3      | 1      | 1
3   | 1      | 2      | 2
4   | 3      | 2      | 2
3   | 2      | 3      | 3
```

This is the table i wish to query the results twice from based on the `heatNumber` value. `heatNumber` values are static and they're `1` AND `4`.

So i want my query to return results from table `motos` if `heatNumber` is `1` and return results from table `motos` if `heatNumber` is `4` and limit my results to `tourneyId` and `ageId`.

So if i'd query results with `tourneyId = 1` and `ageId = 1` then the results would be:

Result:

```
tp_id | result_when_heat_number_is_1 | result_when_heat_number_is_4 | sum_of_results
1     | 1                            | 1                            | 2
2     | 2                            | 2                            | 4
```

I tried to write the query, but as i'm not so familiar with SQL i have failed miserably (unfinished and already broken):

```
SELECT tp.tp_id, m1.result as r1, m2.result as r2 
FROM tourneyplayers tp, motos m1, motos m2 
INNER JOIN heats as h1 ON (m2.idHeat = h1.heatId) 
INNER JOIN heats as h2 ON (m1.idHeat = h2.heatId) 
WHERE tp.tp_id = m1.tpid
AND tp.tp_id = m2.tpid
AND tp.tourneyId = 115 
AND ageId = 16
```

I'm not sure if i'm on the right path with that one, i tried joining heats twice for both motos, but this gave me an error  `#1054 - Unknown column 'm1.idHeat' in 'on clause'` and I ran out of ideas. Hope anyone can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with joins definition in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT tp.tp_id, m1.result as r1, m2.result as r2 
FROM tourneyplayers tp, motos m1, motos m2 
,heats h1, heats as h2
WHERE tp.tp_id = m1.tpid
AND tp.tp_id = m2.tpid
AND tp.tourneyId = 115 
AND ageId = 16
AND m2.idHeat = h1.heatId
AND m1.idHeat = h2.heatId
```

Comment: Adding heatNumber = 1 & heatnumber = 4 resolved the issue, as you were quicker (and gave the same result as @scaisEdge) below, i mark you as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

be sure you have a idHeat in motos and 
don't mix implicit and explicit join

```
  SELECT 
    tp.tp_id
    , m1.result as r1
    , m2.result as r2 
  FROM tourneyplayers tp
  INNER JOIN motos as m1 ON tp.tp_id = m1.tpid 
  INNER JOIN motos as m2 ON tp.tp_id = m2.tpid 
  INNER JOIN heats as h1 ON m2.idHeat = h1.heatId 
  INNER JOIN heats as h2 ON m1.idHeat = h2.heatId 
  WHERE  tp.tourneyId = 115 
  AND ageId = 16
```